# Tight and Narrow = Eng und Schmal?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

I've been trying to learn the vocabulary for both 'tight' and 'narrow', but I am having trouble with the translation.  There seems to be some overlap.  I'll give a couple of example sentences and my attempts at translating them:

1) My belt is **tight**. = Mein Gürtel ist **eng**.

2) The road is **narrow**. = Die Straße ist **schmal**.

Is this correct?  Does 'tight' (as in: tight clothes) translate to 'eng' and 'narrow' (as in: a narrow space) translate to 'schmal'?  Thank you!

Comment: Seems perfectly correct to me

Comment: That's correct. Tight might also be translated as "knapp", depending on situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your translations are correct, but as you said the meanings of tight and narrow can overlap sometimes.

Your example: "The road is **narrow**" could also mean "Die Straße ist **eng**", but "tight and Narrow = Eng und Schmal" should be right in general

Comment: Also, a narrow spot in an otherwise ordinary road is commonly referred to as "Engstelle".

Answer (score 6):

*Eng* comes from the same root as *Angst* and has a background of restraint. We could also call it *narrow by force*.

*schmal* is related to the English *small* and talks about the natural state of something.

So, and this is to be taken just as a guide line, you would use *eng* whenever there is a restrictive force involved whereas *schmal* is proper for things and persons that are small breadth-wise.
If you say

> Mein Gürtel ist schmal.

that means that it is a slim belt.

> Die Strasse ist eng.

focuses more on how for example the buildings squeeze together the street.

Comment: My intuition for these is that **eng** refers more to the relationship between two objects while **schmal** is for a characteristic of an object. Kind of like this post, where *Die Straße ist schmal* focuses on the breadth of a street, while *Die Straße ist eng* suggests there is an external reason why the street is narrow. I'm not sure how exactly to articulate it.